# Element wise comparison in an array of arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have the following array of `shape(5,2,3)`, which is a collection of `2 * 3` arrays.

```
a = array([[[ 0,  2,  0],
    [ 3,  1,  1]],

   [[ 1,  1,  0],
    [ 2,  2,  1]],

   [[ 0,  1,  0],
    [ 3,  2,  1]],

   [[-1,  2,  0],
    [ 4,  1,  1]],

   [[ 1,  0,  0],
    [ 2,  3,  1]]])
```

**1)** How can I check if there exists a `2 * 3` array in this array of arrays where at least one element is negative in it?

```
#which is this:
[[-1,  2,  0],
[ 4,  1,  1]]
```

**2)** After that how can I remove the above found `2 * 3` array from `a`?

A vectorized implementation is much appreciated but looping is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do -

```
a[~(a<0).any(axis=(1,2))]
```

Or the equivalent with `.all()` and thus avoid the `inverting` -

```
a[(a>=0).all(axis=(1,2))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [35]: a
Out[35]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  0],
        [ 3,  1,  1]],

       [[ 1,  1,  0],
        [ 2,  2,  1]],

       [[ 0,  1,  0],
        [ 3,  2,  1]],

       [[-1,  2,  0],
        [ 4,  1,  1]],

       [[ 1,  0,  0],
        [ 2,  3,  1]]])

In [36]: a[~(a<0).any(axis=(1,2))]
Out[36]: 
array([[[0, 2, 0],
        [3, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `any`:

```
In [10]: np.any(a<0,axis=-1)
Out[10]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Or more complete, if you want the corresponding index for (2,3) array:

```
In [22]: np.where(np.any(a<0,axis=-1).any(axis=-1))
Out[22]: (array([3]),)
# Or as mentioned in comment you can pass a tuple to `any` np.where(np.any(a<0,axis=(1, 2)))
```

You can also get the array with a simple indexing:

```
In [27]: a[np.any(a<0, axis=(1, 2))]
Out[27]: 
array([[[-1,  2,  0],
        [ 4,  1,  1]]])
```

Comment: You can also pass a tuple to np.any: `np.any(a<0, axis=(1, 2))`